# Fail to construct a POST Request instance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request. Following snippet can construct a POST Request instance in JavaScript.

```
var myRequest = new Request('http://localhost/api', {method: 'POST', body: '{"foo":"bar"}'});

var myURL = myRequest.url; // http://localhost/api
var myMethod = myRequest.method; // POST
var myCred = myRequest.credentials; // omit
var bodyUsed = myRequest.bodyUsed; // true
```

But in my Chrome browser, I got an instance without body but actually I passed the option with body to `Request`.
[image]

So how can I construct a POST Request?

Answer (score 0):

As Request is still experimental, i would go with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to make a POST request.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not all is documented on [MDN Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request). I reproduced OP sample but when I add the code from the next paragraph result was different.

```
    function doReq() {
        var myRequest = new Request('json.php', { method: 'POST', body: '{"foo":"bar"}' });

        console.log(myRequest);
        //return; //when uncommented returns bodyUsed: false
        //when commented bodyUsed: true and body goes to the server
        console.log(JSON.stringify(myRequest)); //{} all the time
        fetch(myRequest)
.then(function(response) {
    if(response.status == 200) return response.json();
    else throw new Error('Something went wrong on api server!');
})
.then(function(response) {
    console.debug(response);
    // ...
})
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
```

Test cases:
FF 47.0.1 - as above.
Google Chrome 51 - as above
Edge - 'Request' is undefined (as expected)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request. The Request does not have the body property. So you can not see it in your chrome consolelog.

But your request does have the body property, and you can use it actually. When I fetch the request, I get the body actually.  Here is my test result.
[test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbTGY.png)

If you have other questions, just leave a comment.